# How to stop iTunes from automatically downloading purchased TV shows?

Tags: itunes, appletv, itunes-store, television

I was running out space on the drive where I stored my iTunes media, because every time I opened iTunes, the application would immediately begin downloading TV shows I had purchased on my Apple TV.

How can you stop iTunes from downloading purchased TV shows whenever you open it?

**See my answer below**

**Note**: Though it may or may not be entirely relevant to the problem (this bug has bit me across versions of iTunes and OS X), the bug was reproduced and eradicated using **iTunes 11.1.3 under Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks**

**Possibly related detail**: I write *possibly*, because I've modified where my iTunes media lives outside of the iTunes defaults.

*This is a common thing to do*, when you realize the space on the meager 128 GB drive that came with your computer will no longer suffice.

This detail also warrants mentioning, because the use case deviates slightly from the norm, and **pathing often emerges as the culprit in software-related bugs**.

**Another possibly related detail**: I've moved the location of my iTunes media a couple of times, but didn't delete the old location's directory, which is also a parent directory of my current iTunes media location. I've been meaning to re-organize, but there were music files I didn't want to lose at the time I made to the decision to change the media location a second time.

I mention this, because as a software engineer I've run into stupid bugs and relative vs. absolute path issues simply because a user chose to nest directories awkwardly or carelessly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ultimately, I was able to **stop iTunes from automatically downloading TV shows** with the following steps:

1. With iTunes open select *iTunes > Preferences...* and click the *Store* tab
2. **If checked, uncheck checkbox *Always check for available downloads***
3. **If checked, uncheck checkbox *Download pre-orders when available***
4. Click the *OK* button, and **close iTunes**
5. Remove the contents of your `Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Downloads` directory. You should be able to do that through Finder or by following these steps:

   1. Open *Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app*
   2. Type `rm -rf ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Downloads/*` then press `<Enter>`to **delete the plist file along with all of the downloads of TV shows**. (Note: this method removes the files permanently, which is fine since the next step re-downloads them.)
6. Re-open iTunes. There shouldn't be TV shows automatically downloading any longer when you open iTunes. Breath. Relax. Rejoice.

Comment: OMG, you **ROCK**. Thanks! You make a great point about being aware of the iTunes folder location. I ran your command line example, deleted `tmp` files, but that did not do the trick. I realized that my actual iTunes media folder is on another drive. Once I deleted those files, the download stopped. Breath. Relax. Rejoice! :D

Comment: @mhulse thank you :) I'm so glad this helped someone else.

Comment: @mkelley33 do you know if this will also prevent automatic downloads of new music purchases, e.g. music purchased on another device?

Comment: @tnorthcutt I don't know. I seem to recall that setting being somewhere else in iTunes preferences.

Comment: Does anyone know how to undo this terminal code? I put it in and the movies stopped downloading, but now some of my music has an exclamation point next to it saying it has been moved. Thanks!

Comment: @Emily The `rm` command deletes the files without you seeing them in the trash, so you would have to restore them from a back up or re-download them from Apple.

Comment: Please, please, please, PLEASE, change the terminal command to `cd ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Downloads`. This specifies an absolute directory path, and will handle cases where the user has munged something up.

Comment: A much better solution, assuming the `plist` files are in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Downloads` directly (not a sub directory) would be to do: `rm ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Downloads/*plist`, which will just delete any plist files in the Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Downloads directory

Comment: @FakeName I think that's a great solution too. In my case I wanted to also delete the partially downloaded TV shows. Will simply removing the plist files clean up the partial downloads as well?

Comment: @mkelley33 - Probably not, but I think you can then clean those up through itunes. Basically, I'm just a little worried because someone commented (in a now deleted answer) saying they tried to follow your directions, made a mistake somewhere, and accidentally deleted the entire contents of their home directory. I'd assume they managed to do something stupid in the `cd` command, and basically ran `rm -rf ~/`. `rm` does not use the trash can. It does immediate, nearly irreversible deletes.

Comment: @FakeName you make a good point about the mistake the user made. I'll add a note in there that users should be careful when performing step #7 in my answer. Thanks for adding your input to this solution. There are probably even more ways to skin this cat ;)

Comment: I'd say add a step between 7 and 8 that involves checking the output of `pwd`.

Comment: How does one undo this?